# Populating a property that is not a part of the JSON schema using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Name": "John Smith"
    "Age": 18
    "Children" : [
        {
            "Name": "Little Johnny"
            "Age": 4
            "Children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

My Model object looks like this

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> Children { get; set; }
    public Guid? TrackingKey { get; set; }
}
```

As you see the "TrackingKey" property is not a part of the JSON.

I want to have the TrackingKey property to be set with a value that I provide upon JSON deserialization.

The tracking key will be the same for the parent and all the children as well.

However it cannot be a static value that i could pass in with the DefaultValue attribute when I declare my model.

What would be the best way to assign The Tracking Key to a collection of parents and ALL their children?

Comment: First of all, why do you need to define tracking id?

Comment: does the logic to generate the TrackingKey involve external data other than the data in the Person object?

Comment: @Matt.G - yes tracking key is external

Comment: I'm afraid there is no direct way of setting the TrackingKey during deserialization (apart from a static value using the DefaultValue attribute). you could set it after the deserialization

Comment: @Matt.G - that was my backup plan too. i'm wondering if there was any delegate or arrow function etc. that can be used to "transform" an object post deserialization. or i will need to recursively loop every item in my collection to add the tracking key which i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: there are 4 callbacks as explained [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm). But might not help your requirement

Comment: You could use a `[ThreadStatic]` member to pass data into your object constructors, for instance as shown in [Execute code to custom type after deserializing an object from Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29438151/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUIDs to generate the value you need.

```
      string dados = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

Comment: I'm not looking to generate a new Guid in this case. I already have a guid that was generated elsewhere. i need to assign it to all my deserialized objects.